# Javascript cubing function

Tags: javascript, function

So, running into more trouble with Codecademy, and it looks like it's because they are setting up a finite number of passing parameters for the input to their command line, because this javascript function seems to make sense, but it is not accepting it. Is this another problem with basic logic, or is it Js syntax?

```
var cube = function(n){
  return n * n;  
};

var n = 5;

cube(n);
```

I know that it isn't necessary to explicitly create the variable n just to test it, but I thought that may have been one of the conditions to test if the function could effectively pass the 'n' parameter.

Comment: Oops nevermind, it's just been too long since I've been in Algebra class. I forgot it was n * n * n

Answer (score 5):

Maybe because cubing should be

```
return n * n * n;
```